# Issue launching IIS Express

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have an issue running IIS express in Visual Studio 2012 and 2015. This is the issue I've been getting:

```
Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:55920/" for site "SITE NAME"
application "/".
Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being 
used by another process. (0x80070020).
```

I have read the various posts on here and tried the various solutions but they don't seem to work. This is what I have tried:

- Deleting IISExpress folder.
- Running Visual Studio as administrator.
- Deleting .vs folder in the 2015 projects
- Running netstat or tcpview to find the port that is actually using it is not listed.

These are the only solutions that work:

- Restarting the computer
- Changing the port - This works in the short run, but it may throw the same error next time on the new port designation.

I ran these projects before I upgraded my OS, and never had an issue with the ports. For some reason, once I upgraded to Windows 10, I've been encountering this issue. Is there something that went wrong when the OS was upgraded?

Comment: What version of IIS Express are you using?

Comment: @bwegs , control panel lists IIS Express 10, v 10.0.1736

Comment: when you say you changed the port, how did you exactly changed it? from apphostconfig or project properties ?

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek I went to the project properties.